# Barracuda WAF + Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk, barracuda

this is a question for someone who has experience in Barracuda an AWS EB

If I have a VPC with single public subnet and I want to protect a EB with this WAF, how is the better mode to procced?

Regards

Comment: good, actually at first time putting elb address as server. Elastic beanstalk apps are in autoscaling groups so I don't know how to put as an "only" server in waf services. Currently I don't have any EB app crossing by Barracuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barracuda WAF has some issues, I had to create a large set of virtual private IPs to use the WAF successfully & it can't auto-add servers from an auto scaling group.

It's best to put the WAF in front of the *ELB* of the autoscaling group instead. That relies on static IPs but is otherwise quite good. Make sure to use an instance type large enough for your bandwidth needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer now my question based in your answer is how I set the service in the waf?

Comment: They're added in via the WAF's Web interface. It should handle being the HTTPS end point so it can decrypt and scan incoming traffic.

Comment: ok I know it is via web interface. what I mean is how to add such service being an EB :)

Comment: @Néstor Ok! The Barracuda unfortunately only takes IP addresses for its services, so the trick is getting your EB to use a single static IP the Barracuda can track. That is done using a VPC with private and public IPs and explained a bit better here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26390610/static-ip-using-elastic-beanstalk

Comment: So is doing al EB single instances

Comment: It can be done via either single instances with an EIP assigned, or ELB instances with an EIP.

Comment: hum.. I understand. So putting a EIP in an oldest instance from autoscaling and changing termination policies in the autoscaling group to **newest instance** is more or less what you say? but then I have to put the additional intances' internal IP in the same service when the EB is scaled to more than one instance?